# Where is Visual Studio's NCB file located?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a suspicion that my Visual Studio Intellisense has stopped working. I have read that this may be the cause of the NCB file being corrupted and needs to be deleted. I have searched for the NCB file throughout my computer but no search results have popped up. Where can I manually locate this file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**If you have one:** it should be in the same directory as your solution (.sln) file, with the same basename.

If your solution is `C:\projects\acme.sln` then it should be `C:\projects\acme.ncb`.

**But:** Starting with Visual Studio 2010, it no longer uses the .ncb system.  Instead, it creates a file with a .sdf extension.

So you should probably be looking for `C:\projects\acme.sdf`.

See [IntelliSense/Browsing options in VC++ 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I swear I do not see on - it's not there! ugh.. I feel like I'm going crazy.

Comment: oh... sdf! Yes, I have VS2010. So I can delete that file (acme.sdf) without any consequences?

Comment: I believe so, but if you'd rather let Visual Studio handle it then you can go Tools / Options / Text Editor / C/C++ / Advanced / Browsing/Navigation / Recreate Database : True, then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks! (Didn't solve my problem with the Intellisense.. but I was able to locate it.. which is what I asked for lol.)