# VS 2013 where is the angular attribute intellisense stored for HTML?

Tags: visual-studio, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I thought they'd be in one of the files located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html
```

But I don't see them. I'm interested in adding my own directives to intellisense as well.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296072/where-is-visual-studios-ncb-file-located) thread help?

Comment: No I don't think so. I believe its the XSD files that define what are valid attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found them here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Schemas\1033\HTML
```

The file is called `angular.xsd`